# cannot sign in to office365 account and fetch emails using imap as they deprecated IMAP

Tags: email, office365, imap

I cannot sign in to exchange account and fetch emails using imap.

I got to find a link from Microsoft (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437) where I have seen that IMAP is deprecated by the authority.
Can I enable IMAP?
Or It is not allowed from now on.

[image: IMAP/ POP server details]

Comment: Signing in _with a password_ is deprecated (or removed) in IMAP.  IMAP is not deprecated.  You need to implement OAuth (eg, using the MSAL library) to log in.

Comment: can you please share any related blog or something where I can get any help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

IMAP is not deprecated, however basic authentication (login/password) is.

You need to use OAUTH 2.0 to authenticate.

There are also couple of steps to make sure IMAP is turn on for your organization:

- In Microsoft 365 admin portal on 'Org settings' screen turn on 'Modern authentication' and check IMAP protocol
- Make sure that for a specific account ('Users' tab) IMAP is turned on 'Mail'/'Manage email apps' screen
- In MS AD/Entra ID disable Security defaults (make also sure no 'Conditional Access' policies block IMAP)

You can find more details here: https://www.limilabs.com/blog/office365-enable-imap-pop3-smtp